Azure webapp create statement throws error
I'm trying to create webapp through azure cli. I do get error as '6.0' is not recognized as an internal or external command. Any idea how to resolve this error?
az webapp create -n testwebapp1 -g test-rg1 -p s1 -r "dotnetcore|6.0"

Above command would create webapp in azure.

Typing az webapp list-runtimes in Azure cli, lists the runtime's name as dotnet:6  so please try like this :
az webapp create -n testwebapp1 -g test-rg1 -p s1 --runtime "dotnet:6"


try using
az webapp create -n testwebapp1 -g test-rg1 -p s1 -r "DOTNETCORE:6.0"

